# Catch an exception, change an entity, commit, and rethrow the exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following situation:

```
MyStoredEntity myStoredEntity = myStoredEntityService.get(id)
try {   
    myStoredEntityService.doSomething()
} catch (GeneralException) {
    myStoredEntity.setFail(true)
    throw e;
}
```

All that code is inside @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). Basically, I want to call to `doSomething` and, if that throws an exception, set a field of the entity, commit, and rethrow the exception. But, it does not work, because the transaction is marked as rollback.

Comment: Can you please post your whole code? I would like to see where you are calling this method.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `noRollbackFor` parameter of `@Transactional` annotation for runtime exceptions what you want to catch without transaction rollback. Something like this:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {SomeServiceRuntimeException.class})
public foo() {
    MyStoredEntity myStoredEntity = myStoredEntityService.get(id);
    try {   
        myStoredEntityService.doSomething();
    } catch (SomeServiceRuntimeException e) {
        myStoredEntity.setFail(true);
        myStoredEntityService.save(myStoredEntity);
        throw e;
    }
}
```